# Delete first lines from a Unicode html file

Tags: linux, sed, text-editing, awk, tail

I have an HTML file that is in UTF-8 format and I want to remove the first five lines from it.

I've tried using `sed` but it doesn't work in this case:

```
sed  "1,5d" Result.html>small2
```

It actually works for other files, but not here. I can't use `tail` because it removes from the end of the file, and the site may be changed later.

this is my file

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Cache-Control: private
    Content-Length: 176073
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
    X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
    Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=jaq52r5vsd04zvffokbutu1q; path=/; HttpOnly
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    Date: Thu, 29 Nov 2012 06:41:59 GMT
    Connection: close

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en"> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

the file link: 4shared.com/document/U8yRa19I/Result.html
here is the  od -c Result.html result:

```
0000000   H   T   T   P   /   1   .   1       2   0   0       O   K  \r
0000020       C   a   c   h   e   -   C   o   n   t   r   o   l   :    
0000040   p   r   i   v   a   t   e  \r       C   o   n   t   e   n   t
0000060   -   L   e   n   g   t   h   :       1   7   6   0   7   3  \r
0000100       C   o   n   t   e   n   t   -   T   y   p   e   :       t
0000120   e   x   t   /   h   t   m   l   ;       c   h   a   r   s   e
0000140   t   =   u   t   f   -   8  \r       S   e   r   v   e   r   :
0000160       M   i   c   r   o   s   o   f   t   -   I   I   S   /   7
0000200   .   5  \r       X   -   A   s   p   N   e   t   -   V   e   r
0000220   s   i   o   n   :       4   .   0   .   3   0   3   1   9  \r
0000240       S   e   t   -   C   o   o   k   i   e   :       A   S   P
0000260   .   N   E   T   _   S   e   s   s   i   o   n   I   d   =   j
0000300   a   q   5   2   r   5   v   s   d   0   4   z   v   f   f   o
0000320   k   b   u   t   u   1   q   ;       p   a   t   h   =   /   ;
0000340       H   t   t   p   O   n   l   y  \r       X   -   P   o   w
0000360   e   r   e   d   -   B   y   :       A   S   P   .   N   E   T
0000400  \r       D   a   t   e   :       T   h   u   ,       2   9    
0000420   N   o   v       2   0   1   2       0   6   :   4   1   :   5
0000440   9       G   M   T  \r       C   o   n   n   e   c   t   i   o
0000460   n   :       c   l   o   s   e  \r      \r
```

Comment: I've just need to remove 10 lines that are before <html> tag

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: ive test sed in simple file and its great but in uni coded file its not done what i think, its remove lines in 2 byte format but what i want to remove this lines for example this lines:"HTTP/1.1 200 OK"in unicode is "00042 42157.."(for example)and i just want to remove this hedears line 10 line from start of file,tnx

Comment: I can't really see what you mean or why it shouldn't work as-is, but you could try a different tool and see if it helps: `tail -n +10 Result.html`. This `tail` command skips the first 10 lines, just as you need (it does not "count backwards" from the end in this form).

Comment: tnx ive try it now but nothing change! and i cat it to file but file is empty: tail -n +10 Result.html nothing changed and tail -n +10 Result.html>ams ,ams is empty

Comment: i think this all is happening because of Unicode format.I'm not sure

Comment: here is my file, :([link]( http://www.4shared.com/document/U8yRa19I/Result.html)

Comment: @arashams: Cannot you post to a free service? The header contains no non-latin characters, so its utf-8 encoding should be the same as ASCII. Utf-16 would be different, but in no way similar to "00042 42157".

Comment: Please post your file somewhere where we do not need to register to gain access. Try [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't access your file so I can't test this, but one of these should work:

```
gawk 'NR>5' Result.html>small2
perl -ne 'print if $.>5' Result.html>small2
```

If they don't work, I doubt it is a problem with the encoding, you may have some strange characters screwing things up. try passing your file through `od` to check:

```
od -c Result.html | more
```

UPDATE:

I see in the output of `od -c` that you have mac-style lines that end with a carriage return (\r) and not a line feed (\n). So, try changing these to \n and running sed or one of the other commands again:

```
perl -ne 's/\r/\n/g; print' Results.html | gawk 'NR>5' > small2
```

Also, please post your file so we can access it and try it ourselves. It will greatly speed up the process. The service you have linked to requires us to get an account.

Comment: i cant get answer and both smalls file are empty :(

Comment: tank you thank you tank uuuu, :-* :) its finally works,

Comment: i cant vote :( because it need at least 15 reputation,I just have 8 but soon as i get 15 i will thank your favor ;) again thank u, and 1 question what is perl doing ? just changing \r to \n ?? why before that we cant use awk?? tnx

Comment: Yes, Perl is just changing `\r` to `\n`. You can't use gawk or sed because they use `\n` to define a line. Since there were no `\n`s in your file, sed and gawk were treating it all as one line. So, asking it to remove the 1st 5 lines results in an empty file since there is only one line in the original file.